# Why did the VAR deny Liverpool a penalty when they played Manchester City recently?

Tags: officiating, english-premier-league

When the game was almost ending, Manchester City player Doku is seen playing a high boot against Liverpool midfielder McAllister, the VAR officials review and then decide its not a penalty which sparks a controversy on whether the penalty should have been awardes or not, is the premier league favoring Manchester City?